# Delphi 5 component that will automatically add "db.pas" unit to uses clause?

Tags: delphi, delphi-5, toolsapi

I'm writing my own component, and I wish it to add `"db"` unit to the `interface` uses clause when ever I drop it on the form, since it has a published event like:

```
TMyDBEvent = procedure(Sender: TObject; DataSet: TDataSet) of object;
```

`TDataSet` is declared in `db.pas`, and I need to add this unit manually, which I want to avoid.

I have seen this solution:

[How are Delphi units automatically added when a component is added to a form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20643519/how-are-delphi-units-automatically-added-when-a-component-is-added-to-a-form)

And this:

[Can I make a custom Delphi component add multiple units to the uses clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14332203/can-i-make-a-custom-delphi-component-add-multiple-units-to-the-uses-clause)

That use `RegisterSelectionEditor`, but Delphi 5 (I know...) seems to not have this unit.

What are my options?

Comment: Search in the source code for the unit that does export that function. Things have probably just been moved around in the D6 design time rework.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I did not found `RegisterSelectionEditor` in the source code.

Comment: You can try aliasing the type within your component's unit using an identical name: `TDataSet = Db.TDataSet;` Whenever you drop your component on a form, Delphi should add its unit to the uses clause. Then whether or not you use `Db` in that form, there's a valid `TDataSet` equivalent to the one from `Db`.

Comment: @zig `TSelectionEditor` and `RegisterSelectionEditor()` are not available in Delphi 5, they were added in Delphi 6.

Comment: @CraigYoung, You workaround works. could there be any side effects/implications/conflicts issues to such type aliasing? are there any other known components that uses this trick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can alias the type within your component's unit using an identical name:

```
type
  TDataSet = Db.TDataSet;
```

Whenever you drop your component on a form, Delphi should add its unit to the uses clause. Then whether or not you use `Db` in that form, there's a valid `TDataSet` equivalent to the one from `Db`.

> Could there be any side effects/implications/conflicts issues to such type aliasing?

*From a language perspective, no*.

Generally it's ill-advised to have types with the same name as this can cause problems when 2 pieces of code (sometimes even within the same unit) seem to use the same type, but they are actually different types internally. *However, in this case the types are actually the **same***.

*From an IDE perspective, not much*.

- A minor issue is that "Find Declaration" in the IDE will require an extra step to reach the underlying type.
- The other issue is related to *code completion*. I have experienced that some versions of Delphi would occasionally struggle with code completion when this slightly unusual referencing technique `<unit-name>.<type-name>` is used. (I don't recall how (or even if) Delphi 5 was affected though.)

> Are there any other known components that uses this trick?

I don't know of any components using the technique. But I've used aliasing for various reasons on quite a few occasions. Primarily just to avoid forcing knock-on dependencies on client units.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure if I'm going to actually use this in my component, but it's a nice trick which *seems* to work without issues. I don't think there is another way in D5.